# How to make Sendbird api call?

Tags: android, sendbird

I want to make below sendbird api call programmatically in android?

```
api.sendbird.com/user/unblock

{
    "auth": "6608ae9756272c057058ccb2a644c4c",
    "id": "c87-8a8e-5a8c27b28976appkey7C3BF751-ECA6-4DB7-B117-04A275A066A5-1fef1b1b-c05d-4",                 
     "target_id": "b076-40e9-bd0af580-d42678f-275-e8caad" 
}
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Without more specifics, all we can answer is that you need to set up your project to make HTTP requests. In Android, you can do this natively, but the easiest method is to use a library, like [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Once you're able to make requests, read about the [Sendbird API](https://www.gitbook.com/book/sendbird/sendbird-server-api/details) and learn which endpoints are required to get the information you need. You'll have to work out authentication and user registration and channels to get messaging to work.